# Use the column order in Finder List view for all folders

Tags: macos, finder

In my list view, I keep only four columns: Name, Date Modified, Size, Kind

[image]

By default, Kind is the last column. With a mouse/trackpad, I can finely rearrange its position where I like it: in the second column. The final result is: Name, Kind, Date Modified, Size.

When I change folder though, the ‘Kind’ column comes back to the fourth position. Is there a way of keeping a default arrangement for columns in Finder List View?

Answer (score 1):

View → Show View Options (⌘J) and choose Use as Defaults. This uses the settings of your current Finder window as the defaults in the future.

For folders you've opened in the past, they will continue to open with the settings they had last. Each folder's settings are stored in a .DS_Store file in the folder. Remove the file from the folder and Finder will use the defaults next time (and recreate the .DS_Store file with the new settings).

Comment: Is it just me, or does this not work when in the "column" view mode?